# expression did not evaluate to a constant ERROR code

Tags: c

So I am trying to learn C and I am trying to make this code so it will sort of the array's elements from lowest to highest, it's obviously not complete but I just wanted to see the random numbers printed.

Anyway, I am getting an error E0028 & C2131 (Visual Studios) that says "expression must have a constant value" & "expression did not evaluate to a constant." The `int goals[howMany];`is where VS is telling me I have an error

```
int main()
{
    int i, temp, swapped;
    int howMany = 10;
    int goals[howMany];

    for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        goals[i] = (rand() % 25) + 1;

    }

    printf("Original List\n");
        for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            printf("%d \n", goals[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

This is exactly how the code is written out in the tutorial I am watching and they are using Code:Blocks. I know sometimes those two compilers can be different but I was hoping someone can let me know what's going on or how to fix this.

Comment: MS VS is not supporting VLAs.

Comment: But its not problem for you, actually you dont need VLA

Comment: Sooooo? What can I do?

Comment: What can you do? Think how to avoid using VLAs. This is what programmers do - solving problems. And knowing what problem is - is a halfway to the solution.

Comment: `int howMany = 10;` --> `enum { howMany = 10};`

Comment: Oh well, I am still learning. I just was watching tutorials and then saving the code written to just have on hand to review now and again.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `goals[howMany]` would be creating a list of 10 elements, but you are initialising it as an int. I think it should be initialised as a **list**, not an int.

Comment: Thanks.....now to learn what enum does and how to use it!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use rand(), you need to include the according lib and then "plant a rand seed" : take a look at [C Rand Function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)

Comment: I dont think its an answer to problem.

Comment: I did what BLUEPIXY said and `rand()` worked just fine but I will check out that tutorial

Comment: @KaseyMichael: Check out this answer about the seed for rand(). https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255330/4238087

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio doesn't support variable length arrays.  C is a little tricky, and the compiler/flags you use matters.  For example, if you were to compile with the gcc compiler, using the -std=c99 flag would allow you to run your code with no errors (since -std=c99 supports variable length arrays).

I'm not sure exactly how compilation in Visual Studio works, but that's your problem.  I usually don't like C programming in VS for this reason.  It's much easier for me to use something like Vim, and compile at the command like so that I can specify compiler settings.

Answer (score -1):

```
const howMany = 10;
```

This most likely is just the compiler you are using. I suppose it's a safe guard to prevent a segmentation fault. If howMany variable is changed after being used to initialize the array then a seg fault will  will definitely result.A seg fault is when you access something out of bounds.  If you try to change a const variable then the compiler will not let you.By making howMany const this will prevent any such errors.